# Is there any standards that will differentiate reading $x+y^3$ to $(x+y)^3$?

Tags: education

Which of the following is read as "x plus y cube"?

a. $x+y^3$

b. $(x+y)^3$

Is there any standard in reading expressions that will address this question?

Comment: I would say $(a)$. One can differentiate the two by saying for example "the expression $x$ plus $y$ all cubed" for $(b)$.

Comment: exponentiation has higher priority than addition, so $a$ is the correct one if there are no parantheses. This also follows from "multiplication/division before addition/subtraction"

Comment: To me this comes down to the cadence with which it is said. So, "$x$ ... plus $y$ cubed" and "$x$ plus $y$, **cubed**"

Comment: Realistically, I could imagine myself saying either one as "$x$ plus $y$ cubed" if I was writing it on the board at the same time or if I felt certain that the person I was talking to understood what I meant. To avoid ambiguity, I would read (b) as "$x$ plus $y$, in brackets, cubed."